# Phpmyadmin cannot read scientific notations in csv file

Tags: mysql, database, csv, scientific-notation

I tried to import my csv file (contains scientific notations) and the system can't read them. Here's what popped out after i tried importing the csv file.

`MySQL said:

## 1264 - Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1`

That's because the value in column 'id' at row 1 is in scientific notation but mysql read it as decimal. How do i convert the notations automatically?

Comment: Can you show us an example of what the lines in your CSV File look like?

Comment: Any code sample and csv lines example?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9NjYkwfFlyfZ0FPVjNKV0x4MlE here is the sample datasets

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547288/importing-data-from-csv-file-into-mysql-scientific-notation Unfortunately, there isn't any answer there.