# Laravel 7.x: PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bigint

Tags: laravel, postgresql, bigint

I'm using laravel with sometimes very large numbers combined with postgres. In a problematic case I am trying to store data in this table.

```
        Schema::create('address_statistics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('address')->nullable()->index();
            $table->bigInteger('transaction_count');
            $table->bigInteger('balance');
            $table->dateTime('first_transaction');
            $table->dateTime('last_transaction');
        });
```

Example (pseudo code):

```
$testnumber = "13159750.11391604"; //comes from an API as string
$this->addressStatistic->balance = floatval($response["result"]["amount"]) * 100000000;
$this->addressStatistic->save();
```

In that case I receive an error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bigint: "1.3159750113916E+15"
```

Is there any way to get around it?

Comment: Not sure about Postgresql. but try this. Your DB column `balance` has data type `bigInteger` and you are trying to insert a scientific notation to that column(`floatval($response["result"]["amount"]) * 100000000` creates a scientific notation). Either convert the data type to `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6401185/6274211) or use numeric literals instead of scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

I explicitly parsed the number with inval() before inserting into the database. Now it works as expected!